# \bibliographystyle{quantum} has problems breaking URLs

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, urls, bibliographystyle

I am having trouble breaking a **specific** URL in a bibliography styled as:

```
\bibliographystyle{quantum}
```

Here is a minimal example that highlights the problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{url} % In the next lines I am already trying to fix the problem [spoiler: doesn't work!]
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/}
\def\UrlSpecials{
  \do\.{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`.}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue
}

\title{Minimal Example}
\author{Author}
\date{September 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
ahaha \cite{IBMstatevec}

bsbsbs \cite{IBMdynamic}

\bibliographystyle{quantum}
\bibliography{lib.bib}

\end{document}
```

The output of this is as follows.
[image]

You can see that whilst the link of the second reference is broken appropriately, the link of the first one is not, and is overflowing into the second column of the document.

The .bib file looks like this:

```
@website{IBMstatevec,
    author = {Qiskit Development Team},
    title = {Statevector{S}imulator},
    year = {2022},
    url = {https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.StatevectorSimulator.html},
    urldate = {2022-11-01}
}

@website{IBMdynamic,
    author = {Blake Johnson},
    title = {Bringing the full power of dynamic circuits to {Q}iskit {R}untime},
    year = {2022},
    url = {https://research.ibm.com/blog/quantum-dynamic-circuits},
    urldate = {2022-11-09}
}
```

Now, in the tex code I put above, you see that I have already tried to fix it using strategies that I have collected from different places.
Other than the attempted solution that you see above I have also tried using:

- `\usepackage{xurl}`;
- `\sloppy` before generating the bibliography;
- `\usepackage{breakurl}`;
- and `\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}`.

However, none of these fix the problem with the link of reference [1].

Can anyone fix this minimal example using a different solution?

Changing the bibliography style, for instance to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` immediately corrects the problem with the URLs, but I want a solution that preserves the `\bibliographystyle{quantum}`.

Comment: The example works just fine for me using `xurl` and pdflatex. The URLs are broken nicely. Note that I also removed your two `\Url...` redefs

Comment: xurl works fine for me too. Show your log-file.

Comment: I can reproduce this in TL 2022, it is fixed in TL 2023, I believe by [this commit](https://github.com/quantum-journal/quantum-journal/commit/261d88f62f2a146b653ee28cbca164f52c102015)

Comment: It is interesting that it works correctly for some users.
@UlrikeFischer should I out the log file in the question?

Comment: @DaiBowen am working in Overleaf. How can I include the modification from the commit you linked? I see no .bst file in my Overleaf document.

Comment: It should work if you copy a current bst to your document folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No that does not work. I had already tried uploading the current .bst file into my Overleaf Project with this minimal example and still, I get the same output with the overflowing URL.

Comment: ask the overleaf support for help.

Comment: Uploading the .bst file seems to have worked after all. Thanks for your support!